# React Native - Concat string in require source image, not work

Tags: function, react-native, ecmascript-6

I pass an icon variable by props, pick it up and try to concatenate in a string within a variable

And I don't understand why this code not found.

```
export default function TabBarIcon(props) {

    var icon = props.icon ? require('Assets/icons/'+ props.icon +'.png') : 'Assets/icons/home.png';

    return (
        <View>
            <Image 
              source={props.icon ? icon : require('Assets/icons/home.png')} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

[image: error]

EDIT :

This code works. But is a bad solution...

```
export default function TabBarIcon(props) {

    return (
        <View>
            <Image 

                source={
                    props.icon == "home" ? require('Assets/images/icons/home.png') :  
                    props.icon == "profile" ? require('Assets/images/icons/profile.png') :
                    props.icon == "advice" ? require('Assets/images/icons/advice.png') :
                    props.icon == "search" ? require('Assets/images/icons/search.png') :
                    require('Assets/images/icons/home.png')
                } />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: use "this.props.icon" instead of only "props.icon"

Comment: It has the same problem @akshaybagade

Comment: okay, you must miss the path, it may '../../Assets/icons/,please check your path

Comment: I have package.json in Assets thats provokes that this path was absolute

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try to Run this**
export default function TabBarIcon(props) {

var icon = props.icon ? require('Assets/icons/'+ props.icon +'.png') : 'Assets/icons/home.png';

return (
    <View>
        <Image 
          source={props.icon ? require(icon) : require('Assets/icons/home.png')} />
    </View>
);
}
```

Comment: It says: Invalid call at line 16: require(icon).
I understand that the require of the var icon I remove

Comment: No, this error "Invalid call at line 16: require(icon)", shows without require in var icon ...